# Show Zero's for columns where no records in table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that shows data from two tables joined by the field project_id. No results are shown if there is a record in the projects table but no records in the project_tasks table.

How can I display the contents of the projects table but just display zeros for any fields that don't exist in the project_tasks table?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    projects.project_id,
    projects.project_name,
    projects.project_description,
    projects.creation_date,
    projects.deadline,
    sitelok.Name AS 'project_manager',
    COUNT(project_tasks.task_id) AS 'total_tasks',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN project_tasks.status = 'Completed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'total_completed',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN project_tasks.status = 'In Progress' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'total_in_progress',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN project_tasks.status = 'Not Started' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'total_not_started',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN project_tasks.status = 'Stuck' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'total_stuck'
FROM
    projects,
    project_tasks,
    sitelok
WHERE
    projects.project_id = project_tasks.project_id
        AND projects.project_manager = sitelok.id
GROUP BY projects.project_id
```

Comment: You need to use a left join so rows are included even when there is not a match

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a left join. Can you give me more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting from both tables you need to do a left join onto the `project_tasks` table.

[Read more about left joins here.](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

You query will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    projects.project_id,
    IFNULL(project_tasks.task_id, 0),
    ...
FROM projects
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_tasks ON project_tasks.project_id = projects.id
```

Note how I'm using [IFNULL()](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) so if there is no matching row in the project_tasks table it will display 0 instead.